# How do I fix this depracated PHP4 Style constructor issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

When testing my plugin for compatibility with PHP7, I'm seeing just one error in my plugin.

```
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE

246 | ERROR | Deprecated PHP4 style constructor are not supported since PHP7
```

Linked below is the file hosted on GitHub so that you can see it.

https://github.com/warfare-plugins/social-warfare/blob/master/functions/widgets.php

```
Line 246: function widget($args, $instance) {
```

This is a class designed to create a WordPress widget, but after Googling a bit, I can't quite see what it's trying to say about the deprecated constructor method. It's not using the same name as the class it's in.

So anyways, what do I need to change on that line to make this fully PHP7 ready?

Comment: The constructor method has to look like this `function __construct(...)`

Comment: Are you talking about the stuff up on lines 11-13? Is that what needs to be rewritten? If so, how?

Comment: In PHP4 the constructor is being named like the class. In PHP5+ the constructor is named `__construct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
function swp_popular_posts_widget() {
    parent::__construct(false, $name = 'Social Warfare: Popular Posts' );
}
```

to

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(false, $name = 'Social Warfare: Popular Posts' );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That line number in the error message totally through me off. Thanks.